# Preserving a flag between Angular directive instances

Tags: angular-directive

I have a directive in an ng-repeat loop. I need to set a flag that each instance of the directive can access and change.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form-builder ng-repeat="fl in t.fieldList"></form-builder>
</div>
```

So as an example, myFlag in this directive would persist:

```
angular.module('app').directive("formBuilder", function ($compile) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            myFlag = (myFlag === 'start') ? 'end' : 'start';
            angular.element(element.append($compile("<div>" + myFlag + "</div>")(scope)));
        }
    };
});
```

And the output would be:

start
end
start
end
...

How do I persist myFlag between directive instances?
(Yes, I know that myFlag isn't defined or stored anywhere... that's what I'm asking to do...)

Comment: Do you want to share the flag between all instances of the directive throughout the whole app, or just between those instances in that `ng-repeat`? i.e. if there was an identical `<div class="form-group">` right after the first one, should the "start end start"-list start over or continue where the first one left off?

Comment: The latter, between the ng-repeat instances. The directive is reading in an XML document (converted in objects) that describe a form. It's data taken from a legacy windows app and so I have positions and sizes of elements, but I'm converting that into a responsive web form. In order to figure out where to place the "form-group" start/end, it would be helpful to set some flags. Overly-simplified here, I might read in a label then an input that both have the same "top" value, then the next label and input have a top value that's lower.

Comment: I can use some of this information to determine which label goes with which input(s), and where to start a new form-group. But in order to do so, I need to set some flags and track what's come before it. That's what I'm attempting to do.